# Mathematica: NExpectation vs Expectation - inconsistent results

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Following code returns different values for `NExpectation` and `Expectation`.
If I try the same for `NormalDistribution[]` I get convergence erors for `NExpectation` (but the final result is still `0` for all of them).
What is causing the problem?

```
U[x_] := If[x >= 0, Sqrt[x], -Sqrt[-x]]

N[Expectation[U[x], x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[1, 1]]]

NExpectation[U[x], x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[1, 1]]
```

Output:

```
    -0.104154
     0.796449
```

Comment: I think it might be a branch-cut issue in the Bessel functions... Interestingly, if I use `U[x_] := Piecewise[{{Sqrt[x], x >= 0}, {-Sqrt[-x], x < 0}}]` instead of the `If` construct, then the `NExpectation` gives the same value, but `N[Expectation[...]]` returns the obviously wrong complex result: `-0.104154 - 0.104154 I`.

Comment: @Simon, it looks like it is an `Integrate` bug. With `v[x_]:=Piecewise[{{Sqrt[x], x >= 0}, {-Sqrt[-x], x < 0}}]`, if you try `N@Expectation[v[x],
  x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[1.0, 1.], Method -> "Integrate"]` you get `-0.104154 - 0.104154 I`. If you change the method, `N@Expectation[v[x], x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[1.0, 1.], 
  Method -> "Moment"]` gives `0.796449`.

Comment: @kguler: Yeah, I noticed my original guess wasn't quite right. See my answer for a more complete discussion...

Answer (score 6):

I think it might actually be an `Integrate` bug.

Let's define your

```
U[x_] := If[x >= 0, Sqrt[x], -Sqrt[-x]]
```

and the equivalent

```
V[x_] := Piecewise[{{Sqrt[x], x >= 0}, {-Sqrt[-x], x < 0}}]
```

which are equivalent over the reals

```
FullSimplify[U[x] - V[x], x \[Element] Reals] (* Returns 0 *)
```

For both `U` and `V`, the analytic `Expectation` command uses the `Method` option `"Integrate"` this can be seen by running

```
Table[Expectation[U[x], x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[1, 1], 
  Method -> m], {m, {"Integrate", "Moment", "Sum", "Quantile"}}]
```

Thus, what it's really doing is the integral

```
Integrate[U[x] PDF[NormalDistribution[1, 1], x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

which returns

```
(Sqrt[Pi] (BesselI[-(1/4), 1/4] - 3 BesselI[1/4, 1/4] + 
   BesselI[3/4, 1/4] - BesselI[5/4, 1/4]))/(4 Sqrt[2] E^(1/4))
```

The integral for `V`

```
Integrate[V[x] PDF[NormalDistribution[1, 1], x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

gives the same answer but multiplied by a factor of `1 + I`. This is clearly a bug.

The numerical integral using `U` or `V` returns the expected value of 0.796449:

```
NIntegrate[U[x] PDF[NormalDistribution[1, 1], x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

This is presumably the correct solution.

---

**Edit:**  The reason that [kguler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8562264/421225) returns the same value for all versions is because the `u[x_?NumericQ]` definition prevents the analytic integrals from being performed so `Expectation` is unevaluated and reverts to using `NExpectation` when asked for its numerical value..

---

**Edit 2:**
Breaking down the problem a little bit more, you find

```
In[1]:= N@Integrate[E^(-(1/2) (-1 + x)^2) Sqrt[x] , {x, 0, Infinity}]
         NIntegrate[E^(-(1/2) (-1 + x)^2) Sqrt[x] , {x, 0, Infinity}]

Out[1]= 0. - 0.261075 I   
Out[2]= 2.25748

In[3]:= N@Integrate[Sqrt[-x] E^(-(1/2) (-1 + x)^2) , {x, -Infinity, 0}]
         NIntegrate[Sqrt[-x] E^(-(1/2) (-1 + x)^2) , {x, -Infinity, 0}]

Out[3]= 0.261075    
Out[4]= 0.261075
```

Over both the ranges, the integrand is real, non-oscillatory  with an exponential decay. There should not be any need for imaginary/complex results.

Finally note that the above results hold for Mathematica version 8.0.3.
In version 7, the integrals return 1F1 hypergeometric functions and the analytic result matches the numeric result. So this bug (which is also currently present in Wolfram|Alpha) is a regression.

Comment: Yes, looks like Integrate returns different results: N[Integrate[
  U[x] PDF[NormalDistribution[1, 1], x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]] returns **-0.104154**, but
NIntegrate[
 U[x] PDF[NormalDistribution[1, 1], x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] returns **0.796449**

Comment: @Michal: Yep! That's basically what I said. I suggest you [submit a bug report](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/) to Wolfram Research and see what they think... (P.S. Welcome to stackoverflow. Please upvote any answers and questions you find useful. And follow the [new Mathematica site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica).)

Comment: @Michal, There is actually another issue here: `If` and `Piecewise` behave quite differently as arguments to other functions like `Integrate`. Both in version 7 and version 8, you will get the same results with the function `U[x]`. You need to use Simon's `V[x]` or `PiecewiseExpand@U[x]` to convert `If` to `Piecewise`. Otherwise, `Integrate[If[cond,expr1,expr2]...` always gives `Integrate[expr2 ...]`.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the argument of your function `u` to avoid evaluation for non-numeric values all three methods gives the same result:

```
u[x_?NumericQ] := If[x >= 0, Sqrt[x], -Sqrt[-x]] ;
Expectation[u[x], x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[1, 1]] // N;
N[Expectation[u[x], x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[1, 1]]] ;
NExpectation[u[x], x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[1, 1]];
{% === %% === %%%, %}
```

with the result
    {True, 0.796449}

Comment: It's important to point out here that this method essentially forces the use of `NExpectation` in both cases.  I believe when `Expectation` fails to evaluate symbolically, applying an `N` to it just switches to the methods used by `NExpectation`.  At least this is the case for other functions like `(N)Integrate`.